# Filtering based on nested array return all

Tags: javascript, vuex

I'm trying to create a getter in Vuex that returns a filtered version of a state. The filter looks like this:

```
const state = () => ({
  recipes: [],
  appliedFilters: {
    engineers: null,
    categories: null,
    formats: null
  }
})

...

const getters = {

  getFilteredRecipes(state) {
    const appliedFilters = state.appliedFilters
    let recipesClone = state.recipes.slice(0)
    Object.keys(appliedFilters).forEach((key) => {
      var value = appliedFilters[key];
      if (value != null) {
        recipesClone.filter((recipe) => {
          return recipe.fields[key].some((field) => {
            return field.sys.id === value
          })
        })
      }
    })
    return recipesClone
  }

}
```

So the `state.appliedFilters` is an object that gets it's values changed from a module through an action, depending on what the user selects in a select field. If the user selects "Engineer A" in the select field for Engineers, an action is dispatched and a mutation sets `state.appliedFilters.engineer` to the value of the selection, in this case the ID for "Engineer A".

I want to loop through the key/value pairs of this object in order to see what choices that has been made and then continously filter `state.recipes` until it has gone through all the applied filters. So if I were to use the example above, the filter should return all recipes with "Engineer A" as engineer. If the filter value is `null`, it should skip the filtering and go on to the next key/value pair of the `appliedFilters`, in this case `categories`.

But each time the getter returns all of the recipes. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recipesClone.filter` doesn't actually change `recipesClone`, it just returns a new filtered list, so you should assign that new list to `recipesClone` to reflect changes in it. `recipesClone = recipesClone.filter(...)`.

That's one obvious problem I see in the code. See if that's enough to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it! I'm always forgetting about that. And I usually use filtered arrays with computed properties, so I put `return` in front of the filter function out of habit. So I just get confused with how you use `filter()` in cases when you don't return it directly.

Answer (score 1):

In this function call, you're cloning the array, doing stuff using the applied filters array and then just returning the clone of the array:

```
 getFilteredRecipes(state) {
    const appliedFilters = state.appliedFilters
    let recipesClone = state.recipes.slice(0) // clone here
    Object.keys(appliedFilters).forEach((key) => { // loop here
      var value = appliedFilters[key];
      if (value != null) {
        recipesClone.filter((recipe) => {   // no return here
          return recipe.fields[key].some((field) => {
            return field.sys.id === value
          })
        })
      }
    })
    return recipesClone // return original
  }
```

If you want to return a filtered version of your recipes, you need to return the result of your filtering. It isn't exactly clear from your question how the filters related to your data, but something like this would return filtered data:

```
getFilteredRecipes(state) {

    const appliedFilters = state.appliedFilters
    let recipesClone = state.recipes.slice(0)
    let filteredRecipes = []
    Object.keys(appliedFilters).forEach((key) => {
      var value = appliedFilters[key];
      if (value != null) {
        const filtered = recipesClone.filter((recipe) => {
          return recipe.fields[key].some((field) => {
            return field.sys.id === value
          })
        })
        filteredRecipes = [...filteredRecipes, ...filtered] // ??
      }
    })
    return flteredRecipes;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried it, but just looking at it makes me think that it also would work. The problem I had was just that I didn't assign the `recipesClone.filter` statement to `recipesClone`.